# Google apps script create authentication

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an application Google apps script and i have more than 3 users in this application i want to create an interface for authentication for this application, and according to any user i will open the interface Appropriate to every user.
Some can Help me with an article or with some code please.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I used was:

1. Set up a group "authed" containing the users that are allowed to use the script which allows easy change of authorised people through existing cpanel interface and saves creating a separate store of authorised people
2. Set the script to run as owner
3. In the script,

   a. Get the active user

   b. Get the groups for that user

   c. If that group array contains the "authed" group then go ahead otherwise fail gracefully